# PYTHON: Multiple Substitutions Using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I have lists coming from db of the type:

```
[[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, 14]]
```

I want to convert these like:

```
63 -1 426 -1 255 -1 167 -1 648 -1 364 194 -1 686 14 -1 -2  and newline
```

i.e, separate within internal lists if more than one elements  using  "blank space" and elements within the main list using "-1" and in the end a "-2" and newline character have to exist.
The result entries have to be numbers.
Any ideas (preferably using regular expressions)?
Thank you!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use regexp for this?

Comment: Seems coding directly other than regex is easyer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys. The input is given, coming from another module, so no control on the initial creation.  Only "substitution" types of solutions are acceptable for this reason therefore.  That is why at first my mind came to regex based ones.  Now, if you may suggest, others too within the above restriction, they are very welcome!  But I do not understand the "negative" voting basis...

Comment: Not providing any own effort in question is usually a down vote magnet.

Comment: Thank you @IljaEverilä.  By the way you solution even though helpful does not work on the completeness of the problem.  Suppose for example:  
array = [[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, [7, 77, 777], 14]]  
then, your solution will not work.

Comment: My solution...? Btw if you expect arbitrarily nested lists, do tell in the question. It'll help you get correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a "customer is always right" approach, despite it being the *wrong* way to solve the problem, we could do something with regular expressions and string operations.  To handle arbitrary list depth, you'd need to also include your favorite implementation of a *flatten* routine:

```
import re

def flatten(array):
    new_array = []

    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            new_array.append(element)
        else:
            new_array.extend(flatten(element))

    return new_array

array = [[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, [7, 77, 777], 14]]

string = re.sub(r'[,\[]', '', str(list(map(flatten, array)))).replace('] ', ' -1 ').replace(']]', ' -1 -2\n')

print(string, end='')
```

which produces:

> 63 -1 426 -1 255 -1 167 -1 648 -1 364 194 -1 686 7 77 777 14 -1 -2

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Solution to handles nested lists:

```
final_list = []
my_list = [[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, [7, 77, 777], 14]]

def recursive_convert(item):
    if type(item) is list:
        for i in item:
            recursive_convert(i)
    else:
        final_list.append(item)

for sublist in my_list:
    recursive_convert(sublist)
    final_list.append(-1)

final_list.append(-2)
final_list.append('\n')

t = ' '.join(map(str, final_list))
print(t)
```

Output:

```
 xclip -o > k2.py                                                                                                                                                         
 python3 k2.py     
63 -1 426 -1 255 -1 167 -1 648 -1 364 194 -1 686 7 77 777 14 -1 -2 \n
```

No `-1` before and after a nested sublist as OP says he want's `-1` to be inserted only to showcase a break from the "main list".

---

Solution without nested lists:

```
final_list = []
my_list = [[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, 14]]

for sublist in my_list:
    for item in sublist:
        final_list.append(item)
    final_list.append(-1)

final_list += [-2, '\n']
' '.join(map(str, final_list))
```

Output:

```
63 -1 426 -1 255 -1 167 -1 648 -1 364 194 -1 686 14 -1 -2 \n
```

Comment: @cdlane Fixed the code to handle nested lists. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: There seems to be an extra `-1`, will fix in a bit.

Comment: Can you please try again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
array = [[63], [426], [255], [167], [648], [364, 194], [686, 14]]

out = ''

for group in array:
    for elt in group:
        out += str(elt) + ' '

    out += '-1 '

out += '-2 \n'

print(out)
```

Which outputs :

```
63 -1 426 -1 255 -1 167 -1 648 -1 364 194 -1 686 14 -1 -2 [newline]
```

You don't need to use regexp here, it's even a bad idea, since you are dealing with lists.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't handle the OP's second example (added in his comments), leaving brackets, not exclusively numbers, in the final result, "... 686 [7, 77, 777] 14 ...".